# Zen Cart Google Analytics installation

Tags: google-analytics, zen-cart

I have a problem installing and configuring the Easy Google Analytics plugin for Zen Cart. I did read the documentation, did everything exactly like they wrote, I even got some green notices when I logged into admin panel but I do not see anything where i could configure it. It says that I have to go to configuration->google analytics configuration but the only link I have under configuration header is "my store".

Maybe I overlooked something, I don't know, but I need some guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you can see under "Configuration" is "My Store," that means you have a limited profile.  Get the store owner to go to Admins->Admin Users, edit your account, and set your profile to Superuser.